# Reset the values after first loop tic tac toe c++?

Tags: c++, loops

The game doesn't reset the input from last game. It has the first game's input and won't reset on the loop where it asks if the user if they want to play again. I tried making a void function that would reset the values of the code by having two of the same arrays but it still wouldn't work. Please help as I am fairly new to c++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char matrix[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
const char matrix2[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
char player = 'X';
int n;
int xscore = 0, oscore = 0, gamenum = 1;
void Draw()
{
system("cls");
cout << "T i c T a c T o e" << endl;
cout << "Game #" << gamenum << " Score: X - [" << xscore << "] O - [" << oscore << "]" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
void Input()
{
int a;
cout << "It's " << player << " turn. " <<"Press the number of the field: ";
cin >> a;

if (a == 1)
{
    if (matrix[0][0] == '1')
        matrix[0][0] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 2)
{
    if (matrix[0][1] == '2')
        matrix[0][1] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 3)
{
    if (matrix[0][2] == '3')
        matrix[0][2] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 4)
{
    if (matrix[1][0] == '4')
        matrix[1][0] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 5)
{
    if (matrix[1][1] == '5')
        matrix[1][1] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 6)
{
    if (matrix[1][2] == '6')
        matrix[1][2] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 7)
{
    if (matrix[2][0] == '7')
        matrix[2][0] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 8)
{
    if (matrix[2][1] == '8')
        matrix[2][1] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}
else if (a == 9)
{
    if (matrix[2][2] == '9')
        matrix[2][2] = player;
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is already filled try again." << endl;
        Input();
    }
}

}
void TogglePlayer()
{
if (player == 'X')
    player = 'O';
else
    player = 'X';
}
char Win()
{
//first player
if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
    return 'X';
if (matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X')
    return 'X';
if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
    return 'X';

if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][0] == 'X')
    return 'X';
if (matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X')
    return 'X';
if (matrix[0][2] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
    return 'X';

if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
    return 'X';
if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
    return 'X';

//second player
if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
    return 'O';
if (matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O')
    return 'O';
if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
    return 'O';

if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][0] == 'O')
    return 'O';
if (matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O')
    return 'O';
if (matrix[0][2] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
    return 'O';

if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
    return 'O';
if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
    return 'O';

return '/';
}
void gamereset()
{
for (int g = 0; g < 3; g++)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < 3; h++)
    {
        matrix2[g][h] == matrix[g][h];
    }
}
}
int main()
{
char user;
do{
n = 0;
Draw();
while (1)
{
    n++;
    Input();
    Draw();
    if (Win() == 'X')
    {
        cout << "X wins!" << endl;
        xscore++;
        break;
    }
    else if (Win() == 'O')
    {
        cout << "O wins!" << endl;
        oscore++;
        break;
    }
    else if (Win() == '/' && n == 9)
    {
        cout << "It's a draw!" << endl;
        break;
    }
    TogglePlayer();
}
cout << "Do you want to play again[Y/N]:";
cin >> user;
gamenum++;
gamereset();
}
while(user == 'Y' or user == 'y');
}
```

As you can see the gamreset() function does not work. I tried many ways to figure out how to reset it but it still didn't work.

Comment: If you compile your code with warnings enabled, your compile should be screaming at you that `matrix2[g][h] == matrix[g][h]` *does nothing*. Change it to `matrix[g][h] = matrix2[g][h]` instead.

Comment: Do you know that `'1' == '0' + a` and `matrix[0][0] == matrix[(a-1) / 3][(a-1) % 3]` for `a = 1`? This applies to all the fields of the matrix. You can use this to remove the if-else cascade. Here is an example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Hu7lkbsDXOPeDIZM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `matrix2[g][h] == matrix[g][h];` with `matrix[g][h] = matrix2[g][h];` the reason that doesn't work is because `==` is an operator used in `if` statement and returns `true` or `false` based on whether the left and the right side are equal or not. while `=` makes the left component equal to the value of the right component and as i can see your `matrix2` is `const` which means its values cannot be changed so you probably meant to copy `matrix2` into `matrix` and not `matrix` into `matrix2` you can alse make that using `memcpy`.

Comment: alright thanks for answering this really helped me understand!